# kworker hogging CPU but I don't know why

Tags: kernel, cpu-usage

I'm working on a custom headless Linux system running debian Buster on an ARM processor.

Linux kernel 5.10.72

But recently I saw this when looking at my CPU usage:

[image: Image shows kworker/u8:0+brcmf_wq/mmc1:0001:1, consuming 75% of the cpu]

I believe brcmf is related to the Wi-Fi driver/chip thats being used (the expansion module is a 1DX M.2 module by embedded artists.

I've tried getting perf to work on the system but I just can't.

the other 2 high use kworkers only pop up every now and then and i think they are unrelated, but they do seem to steel some of the CPU of the offending kworker.

The third section of the image is how it looks most of the time.

any advice?

edit with the request by Artem

dmesg output:
[image: lots of warnings]

edit:

After running

```
echo l > /proc/sysrq-trigger
dmesg
```

The new output is:

```
[  875.933977] sysrq: Show backtrace of all active CPUs
[  875.939010] sysrq: CPU0:
[  875.939017] Call trace:
[  875.939031]  dump_backtrace+0x0/0x1d0
[  875.939038]  show_stack+0x18/0x24
[  875.939047]  showacpu+0x64/0x80
[  875.939056]  flush_smp_call_function_queue+0xd8/0x250
[  875.939063]  generic_smp_call_function_single_interrupt+0x14/0x20
[  875.939070]  ipi_handler+0xa0/0xd0
[  875.939078]  handle_percpu_devid_fasteoi_ipi+0x98/0xb0
[  875.939084]  __handle_domain_irq+0xb0/0x130
[  875.939092]  gic_handle_irq+0xc0/0x140
[  875.939098]  el1_irq+0xcc/0x180
[  875.939105]  _raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore+0x18/0x50
[  875.939113]  sdhci_request+0xac/0xcc
[  875.939121]  __mmc_start_request+0x68/0x140
[  875.939127]  mmc_start_request+0x94/0xc0
[  875.939133]  mmc_wait_for_req+0x70/0x100
[  875.939140]  mmc_io_rw_extended+0x1d4/0x2d0
[  875.939147]  sdio_io_rw_ext_helper+0x194/0x240
[  875.939153]  sdio_readl+0x30/0x60
[  875.939191]  brcmf_sdiod_readl+0x8c/0x9c [brcmfmac]
[  875.939217]  brcmf_sdio_intr_rstatus+0x44/0xec [brcmfmac]
[  875.939243]  brcmf_sdio_dataworker+0x114/0x2430 [brcmfmac]
[  875.939252]  process_one_work+0x1bc/0x340
[  875.939258]  worker_thread+0x70/0x434
[  875.939265]  kthread+0x13c/0x150
[  875.939271]  ret_from_fork+0x10/0x30
```

Comment: mmc1? Looks like your SD card adapter is malfunctioning. Have you tried rebooting? Could you please edit your post and add `dmesg -t --level=alert,crit,err,warn` output?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov done! this looks promising!

Comment: 1. You're missing firmware `sdma*`  something - please install it to the proper location 2. You're missing different firmware - that's at the bottom of your screenshot. Please do **not** post screenshots of text, post text instead. What's your distro? If it's Debian or some weird Ubuntu copy, that's not a wise decision. I'd recommend using Fedora (or any of its official spins if you're not a fan of Gnome) instead.

Comment: Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Kernel: Linux 5.10.72+g50f4621268ac
Architecture: arm64
i'll look into your feedback about the firmwares, thank you!

Comment: 5.10 is a very old kernel. The current release is 5.18.12.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov 5.10 being an LTS it, per se, cannot be said "very old" (compared to current) as long it is still supported... You'd be correct however… 5.10.**72** is a very old release of that LTS considering that 5.10.**133** is current ;-)

Comment: I was talking specifically about supporting new HW devices. No matter how big the last number is, it's all the same. You may be running 5.10.943875640375 and it will still not support anything newer than 5.10 (.0).

Comment: I can't really upgrade the kernel to my knowledge, I'm using a board support package by Ka-Ro for an IMX8M module, murata (company that is responsible for the wifi/bluetooth module) also doesn't support firmwares for >5.10.72

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a fix to it, It's the same fix as mengxp, but I will explain it a bit better.

Turns out the broadcom driver just doesn't work very well or something, the main issue is the host-wake interrupt. It generates millions of interrupts, however this dts parameter is optional.

So by removing

```
        // interrupt-parent = <&gpio1>;
        // interrupts = <13 IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_LOW>; /* WL HOST WAKE COM pin 36*/
        // interrupt-names = "host-wake";
```

these fields from the device tree the cpu load disappears. And Wi-Fi seems to work fine afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

im joining to unix stack just for answering this question!

this is realy nightmare think for me because i left linux because of this problem. every i instal fresh linux (every distribution) for firt time boot its just normal but after 10 or more reboot i got same problem woker eating 100% my cpu resource and yes its really stresing me because my Notebook turning so lagy and unusable. not all time but randomly every 5 minute.

i think its beause of my GPU or CPU problem.

and after super long time and full efort to get rid of this nightmare finally i know why this problem apear :

broken WIFI/WLAN on my Notebook!

and after doing this command to shutdown my WIFI/WLAN devices :

Enable/disable networking completely

```
nmcli networking off
```

Just for WiFi

```
nmcli radio wifi off
```

On both cases on to re-enable.

everything back normal without WOrker High usage CPU anymore!

i bet not only broken WIFI but also HDD, USB, Pendrive, Bluetooth.

sorry for my bad english :(

Answer (score 0):

I remove cap-sdio-irq in dts and fix
cpu usage
from 20% to 0.5%

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please consider expanding the answer so that other (in particular less-experienced) readers understand where to change that setting. Also, please explain _why_ you think this solves the original issue.